# Jquery Qrcode Function not working when put inside timeout

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, qr-code, laravel-blade

Please Help Me, i got confused when implementing Jquery QRCODE, i want to create and a modal with boostrap 4 that show qrcode image
when i implement the code like this the qr code is image is showing

```
<script>
$('#qrcode').qrcode('123');
</script>
```

but when i put the qrcode function inside timeout i got error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).qrcode is not a function

(i want to get value from api for the qrcode value) so that i try to mock it with timeout , here is the timeout function that not show the image..

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#qrcode').qrcode('123');        
}, 5000);

</script>
```

thks before..

Answer (score 0):

It maybe including order of library issue. `qrcode` method might not bound at the time `settimeout` function is invoked.

Use `delay` and `queue` method in JQuery instead.

```js
$('#qrcode').delay(5000).queue(function() {
  $(this).qrcode('123');
})
```